# u'-' と u'\u2013' の違いは何でしょうか?

Tags: python, unicode

python2 における unicode に関して質問です。
u'-' と u'\u2013' の違いは何でしょうか。(2013 は - のコードポイントだと思います)

```
print u'-'      #=> -
print u'\u2013' #=> -
u'-' == u'\u2013' #=> False
```

Comment: Unicodeには横棒がたくさんあって見た目で区別がつきません。見た目同じに見えるのに一致しない場合は文字コードを確認しましょう。参考：[Unicodeにあるハイフン/マイナス/長音符/波線/チルダのコレクション | hydroculのメモ](https://hydrocul.github.io/wiki/blog/2014/1101-hyphen-minus-wave-tilde.html)

Comment: unicode に横棒がたくさんあるのを知りませんでした。リンクありがとうございます。

Comment: `"%x" % ord(u"-")` あるいは、`"{0:x}".format(ord(u"-"))` で文字コードを16進で確認出来ます。参考まで。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 unicodeオブジェクト -> 10進 -> 16進 の変換ですね。フォーマット指定子と同じことですが `hex(ord(u"-")) #=> '0x2d'` も確認できました。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`u'-'` はコードポイント `0x002D` の文字で、普通にキーボードで入力できる**ハイフン・マイナス**記号です。ASCII コードの `0x2D` に対応する文字です。

`u'\u2013'` は、見ての通り、コードポイント `0x2013` の文字で、**en ダッシュ**と呼ばれるものです。具体的な用途はよく知らないのですが、Wikipedia の[ダッシュ (記号)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5_(%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7))の項によると

> - 区間や範囲を表す。
>   たとえば10-20と書かれていた場合、これがenダッシュ (10–20)    なら「10から20まで」である。これに対してハイフン (10‐20) なら「10の20」、マイナス (10−20)なら「10引く20」である

だそうです。

Comment: コードポイント `0x2013` に対応するのは **en ダッシュ** であり**ハイフン・マイナス** ではないということですね。`u'-' == u'\u002d' => True` を確認できました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 11):

utf-8 にエンコードしてみると別の文字であることが分かります。

```
>>> u'-'.encode('utf-8')
b'-'
>>> u'\u2013'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

また、Unicodeとしてどんな文字なのかを知る方法があります。

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'-')
'HYPHEN-MINUS'
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2013')
'EN DASH'
```

Comment: 標準ライブラリにそんな便利なものがあったとは... 情報ありがとうございます。